# React app breaks with child compilation and webpack errors

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I just finished the ReactJS.org tutorial and it was functional. Then I added a bunch of comments to explain each block of code, closed down the local server, and went home. When I re-opened it to start tweaking it and trying advanced options, it broke, with several errors (webpack, eslint, child compilation failed...). The only thing that changed was a VS Code update.

The main error seems to be related to webpack, but I don't have a webpack config file, and I'm not using it to my knowledge. I used **create-react-app** to build the app, and deleted the files in the `src/` directory to start from scratch like the tutorial says to do.

**Errors:** (see image)

- When doing `npm start`, it says `1 ERROR in child compilations...` in the terminal
- Must use import to load ES module...
- Child compilation failed...

**Troubleshooting:**

- I removed and re-inserted ESLint config options in package.json
- I tried `npm uninstall eslint`
- Did a `git checkout` of the previous commit (the finished tutorial) which was functional, but it's broken now
- Also did an `npm ls` for reference (see images)

[image: error-screen]
[image: webpage-errors]
[image: npm-ls]

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced this problem, but my problem is that I created a project based on create-react-app in the V16.* version of Node, but I ran it with the V12.* version of Node. So when I re-run the 16.* version it will work, hopefully that will help you